# Error using affiche

Tags: haskell, gtk, monads, gtk2hs

Concerning the writing of a function in Haskell, using Gtk (via the package Gtk2Hs); here are my requirements:

- The function should have the signature:

  ```
  affiche :: ((Double,Double), (Double,Double)) -> IO Bool
  ```
- The parameters are noted (a0, a), (b0, b); the function should use an external function called mandelbrot: if mandelbrot (a, b) is true, then there must be a call to: postGUIAsync affiche2 a0 b0, where affiche2 is (I also introduced my try to write affiche):

  ```
  affiche2 :: Double -> Double -> Render()
  affiche2 a b = do
    C.rectangle a b 1 1 
    stroke

  affiche :: ((Double,Double), (Double,Double)) -> IO Bool
  affiche ((a0,a), (b0,b)) = when (mandelbrot a b) $ affiche2 a0 b0
  ```

My attempt to write affiche does not use postGUIAsync, and it raises the error:

```
Error: Couldn't match type ‘Render’ with ‘IO’
  Expected type: IO Bool
    Actual type: Render ()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `affiche2` in `when`, its return type should be `IO ()`, because that's what `when` accepts. To make it work you need to found out how to turn `Render` into `IO`, supposedly with `renderWithDrawable`.

Comment: hello,thanks, I no more have compilation errors, but nothing is displayed in the window. please have a look at my new question (I am writing it at the moment)